# Delete files that don't exist in another directory

Tags: windows-xp, file-management

I have two directories, such that directory `B` is *at least* a complete mirror of `A`. For example:

```
A/
    directory1/
        file1
    directory2/
        file2
    file3
B/
    directory1/
        file1
    directory2/
        file2
    directory3/
        file4
    file3
    file5
```

Note that `B` contains all files present in `A`, as well as potentially other files.

What I need is to **delete all files and directories from `B` that don't exist in `A`**. In the above example, `directory3`, `file4` and `file5` would be deleted, such that after the operation `B` is a complete mirror of `A` again with no other files:

```
B/
    directory1/
        file1
    directory2/
        file2
    file3
```

For Windows XP.

Comment: Do you have powershell?

Comment: @soandos: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: You could use MS synctoy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not impossible to do this with a batch script. However, the easy way is to use `RoboCopy`. Unfortunately, this is only included in Vista and later, but XP users can install [this resource kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17657) or grab a standalone copy elsewhere.

```
robocopy <source> <destination> /mir
```

From the help (`robocopy /?`):

```
/E :: copy subdirectories, including Empty ones.
/PURGE :: delete dest files/dirs that no longer exist in source.
/MIR :: MIRror a directory tree (equivalent to /E plus /PURGE).
```

Unfortunately, if you are unable to run outside executables, a batch script will be needed.

Edit:

In the interest of completeness, I've written that batch script. Just make sure to test in a safe place fist, though it seems to work. You may want to remove (or comment, chuck a `rem` in front) the `del` and `rmdir` lines for testing.

```
@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set dirsrc=%~f1
set dirdest=%~f2

echo Source: "%dirsrc%"
echo Destination: "%dirdest%"

echo.
echo.
echo Cleaning files...

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:-d "%dirdest%"') do (
    set curdest=%%a
    set cursrc=!curdest:%dirdest%=%dirsrc%!

    if not exist !cursrc! (
        echo Deleting "!curdest!"
        del "!curdest!"
    )
)

echo.
echo.
echo Cleaning directories...

set NLM=^


set NL=^^^%NLM%%NLM%^%NLM%%NLM%
rem Two lines left empty for NewLine to work

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /s /b /a:d "%dirdest%"') do (
    set curdest=%%a
    set cursrc=!curdest:%dirdest%=%dirsrc%!

    if not exist !cursrc! (
        set rmlist=!curdest!?!rmlist!
    )
)

set rmlist=!rmlist:?=%NL%!

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ("!rmlist!") do (
    if exist %%a (
        echo Removing directory "%%a"
        rmdir "%%a"
    )
)

endlocal
```

Usage is rather simple: save as a .bat file (e.g. purge.bat) and call it like so: `purge source destination`. If you have spaces in the source or destination paths, you'll have to add quotes, as with any other command line... command.

I'll briefly explain.

Firstly, files are removed. It runs a string replacement, replacing the destination path with the source path, so it can check if the file exists in the source. This allows me to report which files are being removed, and when I get up to removing directories, they are guaranteed to be empty of files. This allows me to avoid the ugliness of `rmdir /s`, which removes all subdirectories and files, the same as `rm -r` in Linux. Also, distinguishing between a file and directory just by the path in batch is rather messy.

When I get to removing directories, I build a string in reverse order holding all the directory paths. This is so the deepest level is removed first, because `dir /s` always provides the deepest levels last. It will, however, likely be in reverse alphabetical order.

Also, thanks for the bash script Eroen, but I can't read bash ;)

Comment: The directory removal part of the batch script doesn't appear to be working. It's not reporting any directories.

Comment: Whoops.. The `dir` command in the `for` loops was failing when the full paths had spaces. I've fixed that now. It's also been tested in XP, and worked.

Comment: The directory loop does indeed find directories (tested with `echo !curdest!`) but the very last loop isn't deleting them.

Comment: Ah, could you make sure `set NL=^` has nothing (including spaces) after the `^`, that there are two *completely empty* lines after it, and maybe save it in Notepad so it uses `CR+LF` line ending. The NewLine in variables in batch files is [a rather dodgy hack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379619/explain-how-dos-batch-newline-variable-hack-works). Also, try `echo Hello!NL!World` just after the second loop and see if it comes out on one line or two.

Comment: `echo Hello!NL!World` comes out as `Hello<LF>World<CR+LF>`. I tried with both `LF` and `CR+LF` line endings for the script, with no apparent effect. The last loop produces nothing; `%%a` is empty, even outside the `if exist`.

Comment: Ok, I don't see why this is happening - it works fine in XP SP3 for me. You could try [this one](http://pastebin.com/KChzAZiY), or the algorithm could be modified. A temporary file could be used, or the directories could be straight out removed, ignoring subfolders of removed folders (they'll go, but it won't print a message). Or the whole thing can be simplified and all sub folders/files will be silently removed.

Comment: Not sure what was different, but the script on pastebin worked. Cheers!

Comment: I've updated the answer with that. The change was a slightly different method for NewLines - they should be effectively the same, so it's possible XP (or your copy of it) has an older command line version or something.

Comment: It's behaving a bit oddly, saying that it can't find files in _destination_ it's supposed to delete... Also, how do I call this batch script multiple times from another one? Only the first one gets executed.

Comment: @CoreXii Does it print `Deleting <filename>`? Are those files marked as hidden, or system (in *source* or *destination*)? To run it multiple times in a batch file, just use `purge <source> <destination>` or `call purge <source> <destination>`. To run it multiple times in parallel, just use `start purge <source> <destination>`. It'll probably break unpredictably if you try to run it multiple times on the same destination directory in parallel.

Comment: Yes, it prints the name of the file it's deleting... then on the next line, the error "The file <filename> can't be found" (translated). I figured out what the problem is - file names with exclamation marks (`!`) in them! Also sometimes it says "Directory is not empty." when deleting a directory. My best guess it also has trouble with underscores (`_`) in directory names.

Comment: @CoreXii Yes, the exclamation marks are treated as special by the command processor. Underscores should not be special, though. Are you able to use RoboCopy? One of its switches does this exact thing. Or perhaps PowerShell? It's a lot more robust in how it deals with variables. A workaround may be to write to a temporary file, disabling delayed expansion (so exclamation marks are no longer special). However, there are other characters that could potentially have the same issue. If you are unable to use RoboCopy or PowerShell, please let me know; I'll look into the temporary file workaround.

Comment: Alright, I concede. RoboCopy it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not much of a scripter for windows batch shell, but the following works in bash. You could then install [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) and run it. If anyone with more experience with windows scripting wants to port it to batch syntax, go right ahead and steal this answer.

Also, there might be a better way to accomplish this, I did this mostly because it was an interesting challenge, not because I have needed and solved this before.

### Setup

```
$ ls -R
.:
a  b

./a:
i  j  k

./b:
i  j  k  l
$ cd b/
```

### Solution

```
$ for i in *
> do
> [[ -e "../a/$i" ]] || echo rm -r "${i}"
> done
rm l
```

If you remove the `echo` command, the `rm` command will be executed (and delete the files) in stead of just printed. This way is just better for verification.

In my simple "wet" test it worked nicely with filenames containing spaces.